# ¿En que parte se configura la libreria ngx-particlesjs en Angular 8?

Tags: angular, npm, particles

Instalé la siguiente libreria de [aquí](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-particlesjs). Segui los pasos para la instalación, importé en mis componentes la libreria. Me surge un pequeño problema ¿Como lo configuro? Es decir, en la pagina indica algunas propiedades para configurar estas particulas pero ¿Son todas o existen más? y en caso de que existan más propiedades ¿En que parte hay que modificar para hacer cambios? La cantidad de particulas, velocidad y tamaño se modifican bien pero quiero quitar el fondo negro que me aparece, conectar las particulas con una linea,ect. No logro conseguirlo, algún experto que haya utulizado antes ngx-particlesjs en Angular o Angular 8. Si no es posible una configuración personalizada ¿De qué otra manera puedo agregar particulas en un Proyecto de Angular 8?

Comment: Hola que tal! No se si ya te diste una vuelta por esta documentacion https://kain.net.cn/ngx-particles.js/#/v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar esta otra librería, esta tiene más opciones para configurar y mejor documentación:

[Angular particle](https://github.com/ryuKKu-/angular-particle)

El proceso de configuración es el mismo que ngx-particlesjs así que no deberías tener problemas.

Instalación:

```
npm install angular-particle --save
```

Importar en el módulo:

```
// Import ParticlesModule
import { ParticlesModule } from 'angular-particle';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ParticlesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Llamar la directiva en el html:

```
<particles [style]="style" [width]="width" [height]="height" [params]="params"></particles>
```

Ejemplo:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    myStyle: object = {};
    myParams: object = {};
    width: number = 100;
    height: number = 100;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myStyle = {
            'position': 'fixed',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'z-index': -1,
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'right': 0,
            'bottom': 0,
        };

    this.myParams = {
            particles: {
                number: {
                    value: 200,
                },
                color: {
                    value: '#ff0000'
                },
                shape: {
                    type: 'triangle',
                },
        }
    };
    }
}
```

`<particles [params]="myParams" [style]="myStyle" [width]="width" [height]="height"></particles>`

Comment: Nuevamente muchas gracias :D todo va perfecto.